# Smoke from tailpipe when pulling away from idle

Tags: exhaust, mitsubishi, smoke, montero, 6g72

The vehicle is a 2003 montero sport with the 6g72 3.0l petrol engine. I have a strange issue where there is white/ greyish smoke from the tailpipe after I pull away hard from an idle about 5 minutes.

There is no smoke when driving, acceleration, or in cold starts. Coolant level is steady but there is a slight drop in oil level.. I have top up oil like 200ml-500ml every 5000km but this was a common thing before I started noticing the smoke. The tuneup is also good as I see water droplets from the tailpipe and mist when i hold a glass or the phone screen on to the tailpipe. The engine runs smooth and silent.

I did an exhaust smoke test and the readings were as follows if that indicates any issue,

```
              |RPM 870 (idle)|RPM 2350
--------------+--------------+---------
HC ppm v/v    |322           |65     
--------------+--------------+---------
CO % v/v      |0.55          |0.22
--------------+--------------+---------
Lambda        |1.08          |1.10
--------------+--------------+---------
O2 % v/v      |2.25          |2.16
--------------+--------------+---------
CO2 % v/v     |12.85         |13.06
```

I read online it maybe valve seal/ guides but my mechanic says it cant be as the engine runs very smooth and has a steady power delivery.

Is there anything else that may cause such a behavior or can it be the valve seal/ guides?

Thanks alot

Comment: Where you are and relative to temperature/humidity, your engine is producing combustion byproducts including water vapor. After engine shutdown, humidity condenses within every internal combustion engine in motor oil and exhaust system. At engine startup, condensation in the exhaust system begins to heat up and turn to steam and water droplets. Water isn't combustible, turning to steam as the engine oil heats up along with water in the exhaust system. Blip the throttle and you're forcing steam and water out. Normal and you'll see steam in freezing temps while stopped at lights or idling.

Comment: @FDryer thanks alot for your explanation! So this is valid at idle also? as in condensation can build up and let out a puff of smoke when I pull away?

Comment: Air has moisture so it's ingested into running engines. Water vapor is exhausted into the exhaust system and either condenses into water droplets on cold exhaust system parts, pooling, or travels out the exhaust pipe as steam/water vapor. Water condensing in the system is blown out when opening throttle. Good exhaust systems use a form of stainless steel against severe corrosion.

Comment: @FDryer thanks alot for your explanation.. this gives a sigh of relief.. since these are old cars Ill keep my eyes open for any developments.